# How to show one individuals rating of a 5 point likert scale

Tags: info-visualisation, data-display, rating-system

I am working on a 5 point rating system. The **input** is quite set and would consist of 5 radio buttons with an underlying histogram of the number of ratings from other users:

[image: Rating input]

Now I have another touchpoint, where I only want to display/**ouput** the rating of a single person. I don't want to use stars, since on the input side radio buttons are used. On the other hand I don't think radio buttons are a good way to display the rating.

I was thinking about using blocks similar to the histogram, that fill like stars. What do you think about it?

[image]

And now comes the tricky part: I need a similar output layout for another rating, that ranges from -2 to +2 and not 1 to 5 like the one above. Do you have ideas how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Some preliminary remarks:

1. Won't showing the rating of other users influence your measurement?
2. Please use 'official' Likert scale labels https://www.extension.iastate.edu/documents/anr/likertscaleexamplesforsurveys.pdf

About your first issue "I only want to display/ouput the rating of a single person.". It depends a bit on who is viewing it, but in general I think using radios is fine, as it resembles the way the data was entered. If you use a different format, the user should interpret the different format. In doing so the user can make a mistake + it is unnecessary overhead.

About your second issue: I would again just go for the radios. In case you would like to stick to your blocks, I would opt for having 0 in the middle and gray, -1 and -2 to the left and red, +1 and +2 to the right and green. But again, imho sticking to radios is better.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent answer. Also, the assigned values are moot since users will use the same range, thus 1-5 or -2 to +2 are teh same

Comment: My problem about using radio buttons for the output, that the user could think this is again clickable. But on the output no interaction is possible. 
The idea with moving the negative blocks to the left and the positive ones to the right is great!

Comment: I am not sure about your context, but in a HTML one it could look like this

https://jsbin.com/xilabekaji/edit?html,css,output 

so I think the clickability is quite clear.